Set theory on well-ordered sets

Let $W_1$ and $W_2$ be well-ordered sets. Then, exactly one of the
following holds:

$W_1 \cong W_2$
$W_1 \cong Seg(W_2)$
$W_2 \cong Seg(W_1)$


Here,
$$Seg(W, u) = \{x \in W: x < u\}$$
for some $u \in W$. The proof:

But why $(x_0, y_0) \in f$. I see no reason why $W_1(x_0) \cong W_2(y_0)$?
It is true that $W_1(x_0) \subset dom(f)$ since otherwise, $x_0$ must not be the least element of $W_1 - dom(f)$. But what's the isomorphism? Probably $f_{|W_1(x_0)}$. But why the function surjective? If so, it is  nothing to ask.

If $dom f\neq W_1$, then $f:W_1(x_0)\rightarrow W_2(y_0)$ is an isomorphism. It is order-preserving, which gives us injectivity and it is onto because $W_2(y_0)=ran f$. Therefore, the isomorphism is $f\upharpoonright W_1(x_0)=f$ as you suggest.

How is it onto. That part is unclear. Since $W_1(x_0) \subset dom(f)$ but not the entire domain

Notice that if $x\in dom f$ and $x'<x$, then $x'\in dom f$.  Hence if we have some $x\in dom f$ such that $x>x_0$, we obtain that $x_0\in dom f$. But this is a contradiction because $x_0=\min(W_1\setminus dom f)$.
